# "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve" in React app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, node-modules, source-maps, react-scripts

I get this error displayed 4 times in my React App:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'PATH\app2\node_modules\source-map-loader\dist\cjs.js' in 'PATH\app2'

When I checked the node_modules file, I saw that there is no source-map-loader file.

I am using:
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-scripts": "^4.0.3"
and npm version : 8.19.2.

Do you know why I keep receiving the error?

I don't understand why I need the source-map-loader file (which is not in the node_modules) for the project to work.

Comment: I suspect its react-scripts dependency. I haven't used react-native though. Maybe isolate each package by creating a new repo by installing each one individually and testing before adding extras. You can use npx even to just install react-scripts (it has its own version of react so you don't need to install additional react)

Comment: check also you are using one install type too. It might be part installed with yarn instead of npm.